# What would be a good algorithm to find image shifts (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, video-processing

I have a camera from which i receive a ByteBuffer for each frame. I extract a 640px x 480px 11 bit grayscale image from the ByteBuffer and save it in to a short[640][480]. I do this because I won't be needing it as an image and I thought this would be faster (please do correct me if I am wrong).

Now this is done about 30 times per second. With each frame the program will save any values that differ by more than 20 and are smaller than the existing value for the current pixel in to the value of that pixel. It effectively creates a background image in my short[640][480].

Now for the issue, the camera might move thus shifting the background. And the background I get from a not moving camera already changes a great deal (also with great margins) each frame. Really it is only just stable enough to extract big fore-ground objects. So I need an algorithm that can tell me how much the camera and thus the image have shifted, so I know which areas are new in the image but mostly which areas are still usable.

The only way I could think of was to scan the image for each possible shift and see which matches best, because like i said, it might just not match all that well but still be the best match. Is there any better way to go about this? Because this way I would have to scan the entire image roughly 1,2 million times per frame...

Additionally I do not use processing or openCV or any such libraries.

Edit:
I forgot to mention a pretty important detail, the image is a depth map so lighting does not affect it.

Edit: Here's some code, I use the Open Kinect library to retrieve a depth map from the Kinect. I am not yet sure how to parse the information, this is the only way I've gotten it to work so far:

```
public static short[][] background = new short[640][480];

public void onFrameReceived(FrameMode format, ByteBuffer frame, int timestamp) {

    for(int n=0; n<frame.limit()/2; n++) {

        int index = n*2;
        short Gray = (0xff - frame.get(index) & 0xff) | ((3-frame.get(index+1) & 0x3) * 255);

        short x = n%640;
        short y = n/640;

        if(background[x][y] > Gray + 10 || background[x][y] == 0) {
            background[x][y] = Gray;
        }
    }
}
```

I get 2 bytes per frame from which I attempt to extract an 11 bit value that represents how far the object is from my kinect. I have no idea how else to go about this, but it works like this so I'll save that question for later.

Additional Information: frame.limit() is the ammount of bytes in the bytebuffer. frame.get gets a single byte from my bytebuffer. For some reason the kinect sends me the bytes in a backwards order...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration

Comment: Would it be feasible to place a small lightsource (pointmarker) somewhere in the scene to simplify shift detection?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it has to work in a lot of different settings, little can be said about the background. Also, it is a depth map.

Comment: I am no expert, but I think I would approach this by sampling the 4 corners of the image plus the center, and seeing if I find a match in the existing image.  Your sample needs to be big enough to rule out something moving out of the corner frame, but small enough to make it fast.  To rule out lighting shifts from the camera's iris or changes in general lighting, I would do the match using a percentage of the lightest to the darkest.

Comment: @CodeChimp the problem with that is how would you know if the camera moved left or right? If it moved right, the left corners would be gone, the right corners would be new, and if the background was bland enough, all of it would be indeterminable from each other.

Comment: @Mike Exactly... This is a pain...

Comment: @SamuelWillems you aren't going to find a perfect solution with a low res noisy image. I would create an array of about 100 points scattered around your image. I would record the pixel data at those 100 points every frame. Then, if a large portion of them change (say 75%), then you can assume the camera is moving. From there, you would need to look both left and right (but only offset by about 20 pixels) to find the pattern again (again, with about a 75% accuracy). This is time consuming, but probably your best bet.

Comment: Hmm sounds like it... Thanks, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @SamuelWillems if you want to link me some code I would be happy to gander at it. I have done a bit of work with pixel analysis in c++ over the years.

Comment: Sure I can add some code, it's java though...

Comment: Maybe I should drop the background subtraction method I'm trying to attempt here? It might perform better without it...

Comment: Ah, me and the kinect are old enemies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an image library, it will be easier, more robust and more efficient than you own implementations. For detecting background shift, I would calculate the gradient of your image and compare it to the previous one. It may be interesting to blur the image. You can compare using a quadratic function for the error between the former gradient and the current one.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would determine if the camera moved. Of course, some padding and variance will want to be added to "detectChange()", but since I am not familiar with your data results, I could not determine that:

```
//pick 100 points at random
private static Point[] keys = new Point[100];

//initially set to the values of background at the key points
private static short[] keyValues = new short[100];


private bool detectChange()
{
    boolean changed = false;
    int amtchanged = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        //point some variance here for leeway
        if(background[keys[i].x][keys[i].y] != keyValues[i])
            amtchanged++;
    }

    if(amtchanged > 75)
        changed = true;

    return changed
}

public void onFrameReceived(FrameMode format, ByteBuffer frame, int timestamp) {

    if(detectChange())
    {
        //find where they went to determine
        //the camera's pan
    }

    //the rest of your code.

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        //update the keys to the new data
        keyValues[i] = background[keys[i].x][keys[i].y];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, for what it's worth I'll +1 it when I can (if ever). Either way I've decided to go another way on this one.